# Beginners seeking help for the matrix convolution

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
function md1() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c1');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function blur() {
        var cd5 = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
        var pxls = cd5.data;
        var r = 0;
        var g = 0;
        var b = 0;
        var x = 0,
            y = 0,
            height, width;

        function pixelcalculator(pxls, x, y, cd5.width) {
            var canvasformula = ((y * pxls.width) + x) * 4;
            var pixel = {
                r = pxls[canvasformula],
                g = pxls[canvasformula + 1],
                b = pxls[canvasformula + 2]
            }
            return pixel;
        }


        for (y = 0; y < pxls.height; y += 4) {
            for (x = 4; x < pxls.width; x += 4) {

                var ori = pixelcalculator(x, y);
                var modi1 = pixelcalculator(x - 1, y - 1);
                var modi2 = pixelcalculator(x, y - 1);
                var modi3 = pixelcalculator(x + 1, y - 1);
                var modi4 = pixelcalculator(x - 1, y);
                var modi5 = pixelcalculator(x + 1, y);
                var modi6 = pixelcalculator(x - 1, y + 1);
                var modi7 = pixelcalculator(x - 1, y);
                var modi8 = pixelcalculator(x + 1, y + 1);

                var red = (ori[0] * 1 / 9) + (modi1[0] * 1 / 9) + (modi2[0] * 1 / 9) + (modi3[0] * 1 / 9) + (modi4[0] * 1 / 9) + (modi5[0] * 1 / 9) + (modi6[0] * 1 / 9) + (modi7[0] * 1 / 9) + (modi8[0] * 1 / 9);
                var green = (ori[1] * 1 / 9) + (modi1[1] * 1 / 9) + (modi2[1] * 1 / 9) + (modi3[1] * 1 / 9) + (modi4[1] * 1 / 9) + (modi5[1] * 1 / 9) + (modi6[1] * 1 / 9) + (modi7[1] * 1 / 9) + (modi8[1] * 1 / 9);
                var blue = (ori[2] * 1 / 9) + (modi1[2] * 1 / 9) + (modi2[2] * 1 / 9) + (modi3[2] * 1 / 9) + (modi4[2] * 1 / 9) + (modi5[2] * 1 / 9) + (modi6[2] * 1 / 9) + (modi7[2] * 1 / 9) + (modi8[2] * 1 / 9);
            }
        }

    }



    ctx.putImageData(cd5, 0, 0);
}
```

I am a new to the html5 . I am trying to apply this formula to make the image blur, but the web browser shows the error unexpected token on the pixelcalculator function. Thank you for your help , I am a serious new in programming

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error

Comment: I'm curious as to why this is your first foray into programming (I'd start with something a bit simpler). The basic problem appears to be that your braces don't match (I can't use a tool to reformat your code) though.

Answer (score 2):

You should read a little more about functions (*try http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html*)

When you declare the parameters of a function, you declare their names only. You cannot pass values at that time..

The values, you will pass them when you invoke that function..

So the `cd5.width` as a parameter name is invalid due to the `.`

Also when calling `var ori =  pixelcalculator(x,y) ;` you need to pass the variables in the order you had declare them (*and also you need to pass all the ones you will use inside the function*)

---

There are other issues with your code, like

1. declaring variables in inner scopes and trying to access them outside of that scope etc..
2. trying to access properties of an object as if it were an array (*`pixelcalculator` returns an object with 3 properties `r`,`g`,`b` but you try to access them with `ori[0]`, `ori[1]` .. instead of `ori.r`, ori.g` ..*)
3. when declaring objects the key is separated by the value with `:` not with `=` (*as you do in the `pixelcalculator` function*)

In general you must read a bit more about the syntax of javascript..
See http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript